# How to make a smooth transition in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions

Here is the link for my ToDo project: https://unruffled-golick-3d3bc9.netlify.app/

And here is the repository: https://github.com/jcgsr/ListaTarefaVue.

My question is: how could I make a smooth transition between the tasks by deleting them?

For example: when you delete one, the task on the right or left would go smoothly to its new position?

Thank you very much for your attention and time to help me.

Here below it's the respective part of the code in question

```html
<template>
  <transition    
    enter-active-class="animate_animated animate__zoomIn"
    leave-active-class="animate_animated animate__zoomOut"
  >
    <fieldset
      @click="$emit('taskStateChanged', task)"
      class="task animate__animated animate__zoomIn"
      :class="stateClass"
    >
      <span @click.stop="$emit('taskDeleted', task)" class="close">x</span>
      <p>{{ task.name }}</p>
    </fieldset>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    task: { type: Object, required: true }
  },
  computed: {
    stateClass() {
      return {
        pending: this.task.pending,
        done: !this.task.pending
      };
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
fieldset {
  display: flex;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset p {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  color: beige;
}

.task {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20rem;
  height: 5rem;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.pending {
  border-left: 12px solid rgb(7, 7, 150);
  background-color: #0a0455;
}

.done {
  color: #ddd;
  border-left: 12px solid rgb(59, 55, 55);
  background-color: rgb(12, 1, 1);
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.pending .close {
  background-color: rgb(7, 7, 150);
  color: beige;
}

.done .close {
  background-color: rgb(59, 55, 55);
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2px;
  top: 2px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Take a look at the examples in the official documentation - https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Move-Transitions

Comment: Thank you, @IVOGELOV. After reading the documentation, I replaced <transition> with  <transition-group> and the task disappeared. I deleted <enter/leave-active-class to no avail.  Then I replaced <fieldset> with <li> and the task also disappeared.

Comment: If the code in the question above is your Task component and you have a line of such components - you should wrap the whole group of Tasks with `<transition-group>` instead of each one of the components. If you carefully read the examples in the documentation you will notice that they use `v-for` inside the `transition-group`

Comment: It is the Task component but I can't follow when you say "you should wrap the whole group of Tasks". You mean inside App.vue? Anyway, thanks one more time, I'll try reading the documentation more carefully next time. 

One last thing, here's the sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-rgb-y34w7). If you (or anyone) have time to check it out and make me see what I'm missing, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: My point was that you are using `<transition>` inside `Task.vue` while you should be using `<transition-group>` inside `TaskGrid.vue` instead.

Comment: I did try <transition-group> inside TaskGrid.vue. The only thing that has changed is that a task is under the other and not beside it. But the smooth transition didn't occur. Thank you all the same.

Comment: You did not include your CSS styles for the animations during transitions. Perhaps this is why it is `all the same` ? Take a closer look at the examples in the Vue documentation - you can try using their CSS styles.

Comment: No, I didn't. I didn't include the CSS styles because I was already using the animate class. I thought it wasn't necessary, I'll try using their CSS styles. Thank you again.

Comment: That is exactly my point - you are using a CSS class which is not defined anywhere in the code on CodeSandbox (and probably locally on your PC, too).